# graph builder is not released and render is in the background

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, directshow

I had some problems in my app 
I made an app that can detect the available webcams and render them 
we can shift from one webcam to another at any time 
but the problems is when i switch the new render is shown as main stream and the old chosen webcam is shown in the background

Here is an image that shows the prob:

[image]

what i have done is releasing  the graphbuilder and reinit again with the new filter  it works but i'm not satisfied with this logic

```
MessageBox(NULL,"this is the reload","",NULL);
if(this->videoFilter){  this->videoFilter->Release();   this->videoFilter=NULL; }
if(this->mediaEvent){   this->mediaEvent->Release(); this->mediaEvent=NULL;     }
if(this->videoWindow){  this->videoWindow->Release(); this->videoFilter=NULL;   }
if(this->mediaControl){ this->mediaControl->Release(); this->mediaControl=NULL; }
    // and reallocate them
```

Comment: question : is there any alternative way !!

Comment: Have you stopped the old Filter-Graph? With `Release` you do not destroy the filter but only your reference to it. COM-Objects are reference counted and are only released if the Reference-Counter is 0! And if you not destroy the Filter-Graph the filters are still in the Graph and have a reference.

Comment: To better understand what happens in your filtergraph you can register your Graph in the RunningObjectTable (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390650(v=vs.85).aspx) and connect to your Graph with GraphEdit or GraphStudioNext.

Comment: yea i did i have  stopped it but the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't remove the filters from the graph. Releasing them is not removing.

Comment: i did sure i did the thing is that there is a lot of dependencies between this one and other filters so when i remove it the application crashes down  and windows kills the process  showing me the ugly in a MessageBox